# How to reduce gradient pattern to less code

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients

I'm trying to reduce the size of this code the gradient pattern is using, is there a way to do that?

That is all I am trying to do.

Reduce the size of the code.

How can this be done?

Can the code be written in a way that uses less code?

I was not able to figure out how to do this.

https://jsfiddle.net/g3do25pw/

```css
 body {
   background-image:
     linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
     linear-gradient(to right, teal 5px, #0000 5px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, black 10px, #0000 10px),
     linear-gradient(to left, black 5px, #0000 5px),
     linear-gradient(to top, black 5px, #0000 5px),
     linear-gradient(to right, black 10px, #0000 10px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 15px, #0000 15px),
     linear-gradient(to left, orange 10px, #0000 10px),
     linear-gradient(to top, orange 10px, #0000 10px),
     linear-gradient(to right, orange 15px, #0000 15px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, black 20px, #0000 20px),
     linear-gradient(to left, black 15px, #0000 15px),
     linear-gradient(to top, black 15px, #0000 15px),
     linear-gradient(to right, black 20px, #0000 20px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 25px, #0000 25px),
     linear-gradient(to left, teal 20px, #0000 20px),
     linear-gradient(to top, teal 20px, #0000 20px),
     linear-gradient(to right, teal 25px, #0000 25px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, black 30px, #0000 30px),
     linear-gradient(to left, black 25px, #0000 25px),
     linear-gradient(to top, black 25px, #0000 25px),
     linear-gradient(to right, black 30px, #0000 30px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 35px, #0000 35px),
     linear-gradient(to left, orange 30px, #0000 30px),
     linear-gradient(to top, orange 30px, #0000 30px),
     linear-gradient(to right, orange 35px, #0000 35px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, black 40px, #0000 40px),
     linear-gradient(to left, black 35px, #0000 35px),
     linear-gradient(to top, black 35px, #0000 35px),
     linear-gradient(to right, black 40px, #0000 40px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 45px, #0000 45px),
     linear-gradient(to left, teal 40px, #0000 40px),
     linear-gradient(to top, teal 40px, #0000 40px),
     linear-gradient(to right, teal 45px, #0000 45px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, black 50px, #0000 50px),
     linear-gradient(to left, black 45px, #0000 45px),
     linear-gradient(to top, black 45px, #0000 45px),
     linear-gradient(to right, black 50px, #0000 50px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 55px, #0000 55px),
     linear-gradient(to left, orange 50px, #0000 50px),
     linear-gradient(to top, orange 50px, #0000 50px),
     linear-gradient(to right, orange 55px, #0000 55px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, black 60px, #0000 60px),
     linear-gradient(to left, black 55px, #0000 55px),
     linear-gradient(to top, black 55px, #0000 55px),
     linear-gradient(to right, black 60px, #0000 60px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 65px, #0000 65px),
     linear-gradient(to left, teal 60px, #0000 60px),
     linear-gradient(to top, teal 60px, #0000 60px),
     linear-gradient(to right, teal 65px, #0000 65px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, black 70px, #0000 70px),
     linear-gradient(to left, black 65px, #0000 65px),
     linear-gradient(to top, black 65px, #0000 65px),
     linear-gradient(to right, black 70px, #0000 70px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, orange 75px, #0000 75px),
     linear-gradient(to left, orange 70px, #0000 70px),
     linear-gradient(to top, orange 70px, #0000 70px),
     linear-gradient(to right, orange 75px, #0000 75px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, black 80px, #0000 80px),
     linear-gradient(to left, black 75px, #0000 75px),
     linear-gradient(to top, black 75px, #0000 75px),
     linear-gradient(to right, black 80px, #0000 80px),

     linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 85px, #0000 85px),
     linear-gradient(to left, teal 85px, #0000 85px);
   background-size: 165px 165px;
 }
```

Comment: You could remove all `to bottom` as `to bottom` is the default value, it won't do much, but you'll save few characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since the background has a fixed size, you can easily combine paired gradients by specifying multiple color transition points.
- You can also replace the keywords with a value in degrees, and remove the default "to bottom" altogether.

Thus, the code will be reduced by one and a half times.

```css
body {
   background-image:
     linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px),

     linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
  
     linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
     
     linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
     
     linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),

     linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
 
     linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),

     linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),

     linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),

     linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),

     linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),

     linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),

     linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),

     linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),

     linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),

     linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
     linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),

     linear-gradient(teal, teal);
   background-size: 165px 165px;
 }
```